# JPA & Ebean DDL, how to properly generate ids when using the @ElementCollection annotation?

Tags: playframework, ebean

I'm using Ebean as my ORM with Play Framework. In a few of my models, I'm using the `@ElementCollection`annotation.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@Column(name="tag")
public List<String> tags;
```

My issue is that when Ebean DDL generates SQL DDL to define our tables, the tables created using the `@ElementCollection` annotation are using a `bigint` type as their id instead of `bigserial`.

Instead of generating,

```
create table foo (
  id                            bigint not null
  ...
);
```

The following should be generated,

```
create table foo (
  id                            bigserial not null
  ...
);
```

How can I ensure that all ids are bigserials? From my understanding and [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-numeric.html) bigint is unsigned and not autoincrementing.